# Fazer sistema de login voltar para página anterior em php

Tags: php

Gostaria de fazer um sistema que o usuário ao tentar acessar uma url que necessite estar logado o script verifica caso retorne falso ele redireciona para a página de login e após efetuar o login ele retorna automaticamente para a url que ele estava tentando acessar, como posso fazer isso em php?

Comment: voce poderia fazer um sistema de login via modal-js e apenas da um refresh na pagina sem problema de verificar o HTTP_REFERER, ja que HTTP_REFERER nao é 100% garantido.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar `Session` para controlar se o usuário está logado ou não, aqui vai um exemplo de como você poderia fazer esse controle.

***PHP***

```
class auth
{
    public static function logged($url)
    {
        if(!$_SESSION['logged'])
            header("location :".$url);          
    }

    public static function login($username, $password)
    {
        if($username == "usuario" && $senha == "senha")
            $_SESSION['logged'] = true;
        else
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public static function logout()
    {
        if($_SESSION['logged'])
            unset($_SESSION['logged']);
    }   
}
```

E para fazer o controle em sua página faça isso.

***PHP***

```
auth::logged("/login");
```

Você pode estar usando essa classe de autenticação para montar o processo e adaptar ao seu sistema.

Answer (score 1):

Não testei mais sugiro fazer algo nesse sentido:

**página que requer login.php:**

```
if (!$_SESSION["logado"]) redirecionar_para_login();
```

**login.php**

```
if (loginSucesso()){
    $pattern = "pt.stackoverflow.com";
    //verifica se foi direcionado de alguma outra página sua
    if(preg_match("/$pattern/i", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']){
        redirecionar_paginaAnterior();
    }
    else{
        redirecionar_paginaPrincipal();
    }
}
redirecionar_paginaAnterior(){
    header("Location: " + $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    die();
}
```